# I read something that could be Kufr, what should I do to be forgiven?

Tags: fatwa, kuffar

I read poems in Arabic that might have some Kufr, but I didn't agree with it or like it, and I  stopped and made a tuba.

Is a person who reads such things without agreeing with it kafr or not?

Comment: You have made tuba and its good, InshaAllah Allah will forgive you. Lets ask Allah's forgiveness.

Comment: Are you asking how to be forgiven or whether what you did was kufr? Two very different questions.

Comment: what I have done is kufr or not

Answer (score 2):

IMO, not kafer, see [this](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/21249) for more definition of `kufr`.
So as you state, if you don't agree with it, that's not kufr.

> والحاصل : أن مجرد قراءة هذه القصص ليس كفرا مخرجا من الملة ، ما لم يكن ذلك بقصد تعلم السحر والعمل به ، وإن كان الواجب التحذير من كتب السحر بصفة عامة ، والسعي في إتلافها وإعدامها ، بحسب القدرة ، والحذر من قراءتها أو الترويج لها .
>   (the complete text in Arabic [here](http://islamqa.info/ar/ref/115294)).
>
> To sum up: Just reading these stories is not kufr that puts one beyond the pale of Islam, so long as that is not done with the aim of learning magic and practising it. However what is required is to warn against reading books of magic in general and to strive to destroy them if possible, and to beware of reading them or distributing them.
>   (the complete text in English [here](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/21249).

Answer (score -2):

Almost everything you encounter in your everyday life is Kafr. Phones, cars, planes, trains, taps, toilets, TV, Radio, Music, Dogs, clothes, advertising, pictures. The list is endless.

Everything in your life has been manufactured by Kafr, to be offended by a simple poem means you do not have a grasp of the scope and scale of the Kafr civilization.  You are agreeing to the Kufr way of doing things every moment of your life.