# Will Allah forgive me for doing X ? (reference question)

Tags: sin, forgiveness, tawba

Suppose I have done the sin X - Will Allah forgive me for doing it? What must I do to be forgiven?

**Motivation:** We have a load of questions (see the list at the end) on the site where someone confesses to have committed some sin and asks whether Allah will forgive him or her. I think that all of these questions essentially have the same answer and it is counterproductive to repeat it all the time. The sin itself and the backstory of the one asking the question is largely irrelevant.

**Optional guidelines for an answer:**

Feel free to link to other questions where something is already covered in more depth.

- To what extent can a human speak on behalf of Allah, does one have the permission to say whether Allah will forgive a **specific person**?
- What should  a person do after committing a sin?  (kaffara, repentance etc.)
- Could a person be forgiven if he has not repented?
- Is it guaranteed that Allah will accept repentance of everyone who repents?

---

A list of some related questions:

- [Will Allah (S.W.T) forgive me for this sin?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/64862)
- [Are my tattoos and other acts committed during a period of disbelief going to be forgiven?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/18687)
- [Resentment: Will Allah forgive me?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/65507)
- [Will missing salah be forgiven and not punished for?? And can a hafidh go hell?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/65578)
- [Can Shirkh be forgiven by if it is done unknowingly?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12811)
- [I broke a very serious oath, will I be forgiven](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/48905)
- [Will I be forgiven if I can not control masturbation?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12889)
- [Can disclosed sins be forgiven?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/57790)
- [Will Allah forgive me for backbiting in the past since I didn't know?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/13164)
- [Will Allah forgive me for this dishonesty?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/67224)
- [I used to engage in kissing etc but not sexual intercourse, i feel guilty, will Allah forgive me?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49285)
- [I had an unlawful relationship. Will Allah forgive me?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33532)
- [Will Allah forgive me for this major sin?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/67332)
- [I am addicted to masturbating, will god forgive me?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/59785)
- [Will Allah forgive me for my sins (drinking and not regularly praying Salah)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23245)
- [I have something in my neck that ruins my prayer will Allah(SWT) forgive me?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/67736)
- [Will Allah forgive me for what was done to me?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/67798)
- [Will Allah forgive me?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/67919)
- [Can allah forgive me for masturbating?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/68114)
- [Will Allah forgive me for wishing someone's marriage break?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/68229)
- [If a person tells he will commit a sin and then repent intentionally but then regret his sin, will he be forgiven?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/68244)
- [Will my sins be forgiven](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/68568)
- [Will Allah forgive me for mockery of my father during childhood without his knowledge?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/50489)
- [Will Allah still forgive me? Please answer!](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/68779)
- [Can I possibly be forgiven for doing this?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/68787)
- [I read something that could be Kufr, what should I do to be forgiven?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7012)
- [Will Allah forgive me](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/68897)
- [What do I do will allah forgive me? And is this Kufr](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/68951)
- [Can an apostate be forgiven by Allah?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16932)
- [Will my sins not be forgiven if I told people about it?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/51041)
- [Will Allah forgive me for wishing someone's death?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/61597)
- [I had pre-marital intercourse, can I be forgiven?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/61660)
- [I comitted Shirk on accident. Will Allah still forgive me?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/69223)
- [I broke a promise with a terrible condition. WIll Allah still forgive me?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/69315)
- [Will Allah forgive me for violating poor people's right?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/61713)
- [will I be forgiven if I know Masturbation is haram and I do it?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/61817)
- [Repentance from a misdeed: Is there a chance that Allah may forgive me?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/51548)
- [Will Allah still forgive me for this terrible promise?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/69340)
- [Will Allah forgive me? How can I repent?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/69479)
- [Please tell me can I be forgiven](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/69484)
- [If someone asks forgiveness from minor shirk before death can he or she be forgiven](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/69516)
- [Can i be forgiven if i commited this major act?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/69528)
- [Will Allah forgive me if i repent](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/69540)
- [How do I ask Allah to forgive me for my past life and lying about it to protect my wife?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43545)
- [Will Allah forgive me for repenting this sin (masturbation) so many times?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36703)
- [Did I commit a great sin by having intercourse with my same-sex cousin, and will Allah forgive me?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25526)
- [Will my sin be forgiven?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/52325)
- [How will Allah forgive me after shouting at my father?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/52693)
- [Can I be forgiven forse all of the things that I've done?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/45797)
- [Is there a way I could be forgiven if I intentionally eat non halal meat](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46274)
- [How Allah forgive me](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/53522)
- [How can I be forgiven for terrible thoughts towards Allah, the Prophet and the Qur'an?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/29419)
- [I am proud to be a muslim but i said jesus christ is it shirk. Can it be forgiven?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/54954)
- [Will Allah swt ever forgive me and answer my duas?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/55510)
- [I, a 14-year-old, prayed to Jesus as God. Can this act of Shirk be forgiven?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/63286)
- [Will God ever forgive me for taking my cousin's virginity?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/38307)
- [Will Allah forgive me for this sin?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/63524)
- [Will allah punish me and never forgive me?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30061)
- [Will Allah forgive me for misbehaving with parents?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/63585)
- [Will a person be forgiven if the person plans to ask for forgiveness later?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/38442)

Comment: +1 I agree it is a common type of questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are not able to tell you whether Allah will forgive 'you' specifically. Because it depends on whether or not you repent before your death, and on whether or not this repentance is sincere and adequate in the sight of Allah. You need to understand that only Allah knows the eventual fate of a person, and the people answering on this website are not Allah's prophets or messengers, nor do they have a way to gain the knowledge of the unseen.

**Forgiveness after Repentance:**

If a person truly repents then Allah can forgive him/her for doing X. Because X is included in the following verses:

> قل يا عبادي الذين أسرفوا على أنفسهم لا تقنطوا من رحمة الله **إن الله يغفر الذنوب جميعا** إنه هو الغفور الرحيم
>
> Say, "O My servants who have transgressed against themselves [by sinning], do not despair of the mercy of Allah. Indeed, **Allah forgives all sins**. Indeed, it is He who is the Forgiving, the Merciful."
>
> <sup>— [Quran 39:53](https://quran.com/39/53?translations=20)</sup>

> **ومن يعمل سوءا أو يظلم نفسه** ثم يستغفر الله **يجد الله غفورا** رحيما
>
> And **whoever does a wrong or wrongs himself** but then seeks forgiveness of Allah **will find Allah Forgiving** and Merciful.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 4:110](https://quran.com/4/110?translations=20)</sup>

> **والذين إذا فعلوا فاحشة أو ظلموا أنفسهم** ذكروا الله فاستغفروا لذنوبهم ومن يغفر الذنوب إلا الله ولم يصروا على ما فعلوا وهم يعلمون **أولئك جزاؤهم مغفرة** من ربهم وجنات تجري من تحتها الأنهار خالدين فيها ونعم أجر العاملين
>
> And **those who, when they commit an immorality or wrong themselves** [by transgression], remember Allah and seek forgiveness for their sins - and who can forgive sins except Allah? - and [who] do not persist in what they have done while they know.
>
> Those - **their reward is forgiveness** from their Lord and gardens beneath which rivers flow [in Paradise], wherein they will abide eternally; and excellent is the reward of the [righteous] workers.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 3:135](https://quran.com/3/135?translations=20)</sup>

In these verses Allah promised to forgive every sin after repentance, and every sin (by definition) also includes X. Note that this also includes Kufr and Shirk as Allah has stated that He will forgive these sins on repentance, see  [Quran 9:5](https://quran.com/9/5?translations=20) and  [Quran 25:70](https://quran.com/25/70?translations=20) etc. And when Kufr and Shirk can be forgiven so can every other sin since it is less than that.

**Forgiveness in the absence of (sincere) repentance**

If the person happens to die without repenting then he\she is deserving of punishment. However if X does not constitutes Shirk and Kufr, then there is still hope that Allah might forgive him\her if he\she is a believer at the time of death.

> إن الله لا يغفر أن يشرك به ويغفر ما دون ذلك لمن يشاء
>
> Indeed, Allah does not forgive association with Him, but He forgives what is less than that for whom He wills.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 4:48](https://quran.com/4/48?translations=20) also see [Quran 47:34](https://quran.com/47/34?translations=20)</sup>

**How to repent?**

The process of repentance is covered in a dedicated question: [Does the process of repentance differ significantly based on the sin?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/41427/) In short one must stop comitting in the sin, have sincere regret and remorse, seek forgiveness verbally, and resolve to not repeat the sin ever again. In some sins one is also required to pay Kaffarah. And in sins that are done against the people one should secure their forgiveness or compensate them. If one commits Kufr they also need to repeat the Shahadah.

Answer (score 5):

Bismillah. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Sayyidil-Mursalin wa 'ala 'Alihi wa Sahbihi Ajma'in.

---

### I have done the sin X - Will Allah forgive me for doing it?

First of all, we must mention that nature of human being to commit sins is the reason why Allah created him:

> **Abu Ayyub Ansari reported that Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said:**
>
> If you were not to commit sins, Allah would have swept you out of
> existence and would have replaced you by another people who have
> committed sin, and then asked forgiveness from Allah, and He would
> have granted them pardon.
>
> <sup>[Sahih Muslim 2748b](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2748b), [Sahih Muslim 2749](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2749)</sup>

Another evidence is:

> **It was narrated from Anas that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said:**
>
> “**Every son of Adam commits sin**, and the best of those who commit sin
> are those who repent.’”
>
> <sup>[Sunan Ibn Majah 4251](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:4251), [Mishkat al-Masabih 2341](https://sunnah.com/mishkat:2341)</sup>

Quran says following

> *Sahih International*
>
> And if Allah were to impose blame on the people for what they have
> earned, He would not leave upon the earth any creature. But He defers
> them for a specified term. And when their time comes, then indeed
> Allah has ever been, of His servants, Seeing.
>
> <sup>[Quran, 35:45](https://legacy.quran.com/35/45)</sup>

This basically means that no one has "insurance" from committing sins except those for whom Allah wills (Prophets, for example).

In Islamic Sharia there are types of sins, like major and minor and Shirk is considered to be the number one. Shirk is an unforgivable sin if one dies without repenting from it:

> Indeed, Allah does not forgive association with Him, but He forgives
> what is less than that for whom He wills. And he who associates others
> with Allah has certainly fabricated a tremendous sin.
>
> <sup>[Quran 4:48](https://legacy.quran.com/4/48)</sup>

As such, becoming hopeless of the mercy of Allah is prohibited. The Quran declares:

> Say, "O My servants who have transgressed against themselves [by
> sinning], do not despair of the mercy of Allah . Indeed, **Allah
> forgives all sins.** Indeed, it is He who is the Forgiving, the
> Merciful."
>
> <sup>[Quran 39:53](https://legacy.quran.com/39/53)</sup>

These evidences lead to conclusion that **Allah can forgive any kind of sin, be it a number one sin - Shirk or smallest sin** if the sinner does not despair of the mercy of Allah and sincerely repents (makes Tawba).

### What must I do to be forgiven?

In order to be forgiven for committing a sin one should make Tawba.

> According to Islamic Sharia, when an act of tawba is performed by a
> Muslim, Allah generally accepts it. However, that tawba should be
> sincere and true. Islamic scholars agree upon the fact that if a
> person is not ashamed of his past misdeeds, or does not intend to
> forsake those, then his verbal announcement of tawba is an open
> mockery of repentance. Mere verbal repentance does not account for a
> true tawba. A sincere tawba has some criteria.
>
> Ali was asked as to what is tawba, and he replied that tawba consists
> of six elements:
>
> 1. to regret one's past evil deeds;
> 2. to carry out Divine duties (fard, wajib etc.) that were missed;
> 3. to return the rights/properties of others that were usurped
>    unjustly;
> 4. to ask forgiveness of a person who has been wronged by him,
>    physically or verbally;
> 5. to make a firm resolve of avoiding the sin in future; and
> 6. to employ oneself in Allah's obedience, as he previously employed
>    himself in Allah's disobedience.
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repentance_in_Islam#:%7E:text=as%20it.%22%5B27%5D-,Conditions%20of%20tawba,-%5Bedit%5D)</sup>

If a sinner seriously takes the step of repentance - makes Tawba sincerely then he leaves no way for Allah except forgive him.

> **Narrated Abu Huraira:**
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "When Allah created the Creation, He wrote in
> His Book--and He wrote (that) about Himself, and it is placed with Him
> on the Throne--**'Verily My Mercy overcomes My Anger.'**"
>
> <sup>[Sahih al-Bukhari 7404](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:7404), [Sahih Muslim 2751c](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2751c), [Mishkat al-Masabih 2364](https://sunnah.com/mishkat:2364)</sup>
>
> **Narrated Anas bin Malik:**
>
> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "Allah is more pleased with the repentance
> of His slave than anyone of you is pleased with finding his camel
> which he had lost in the desert."
>
> <sup>[Sahih al-Bukhari 6309](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6309)</sup>

Comment: Is this shi'a view? If so please make some kind of distinction. What I mean to say the agreed upon steps according to sunni's are less than those quoted in the statement of 'Ali ibn Abi Talib however they might be included.

Comment: No. This is not Shi'a view.

Comment: Well the source of the quote Na'aruful Qur'an certainly is.

Comment: I gave all the references to sources I used.

Comment: Yeah and Wikipedia is referring to a shi'a tafsir. Your comment doesn't answer my inquiry.

Comment: [Here](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/148902/he-took-some-money-unlawfully-and-he-is-not-able-to-return-it-because-he-left-that-country) some helpful fatwa for the main steps for repentance. (Sunni view).