# Have I sinned if I did not perform ghusl because of ignorance?

Tags: sin, ghusl

As a kid I ejaculated and did not know about ghusl . For 2 years I did not know about ghusl and I read Qur'an . Have I sinned?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/71337/will-allah-forgive-me-for-doing-x-reference-question

Answer (score 1):

You might be excused if you are a new convert to Islam, living in the Dar al-Harb or a remote area where it was not possible for you to have learnt about the obligations of Islam from other knowledgeable Muslims. This has been discussed by scholars under the topic of [ignorance](https://archive.org/details/FPmfkmfk/mfk16/page/n196/mode/2up).

Otherwise it was obligatory on you to learn about basic rulings of Islam which effect your daily life, so yes you have sinned since you were negligent.

> وفرض على كل مكلف ومكلفة بعد تعلمه علم الدين والهداية تعلم علم الوضوء والغسل والصلاة والصوم، وعلم الزكاة لمن له نصاب، والحج لمن وجب عليه
>
> It is obligatory on every accountable male and female ... to learn the rulings of wudu, ghusl, prayer, fasting, zakat and hajj ...
>
> <sup>— [Radd al-Muhtar](https://shamela.ws/book/21613/37)</sup>

Also see https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/32329/ and https://islamqa.info/en/answers/9446

Answer (score 0):

Allah forgave the mistakes of this ummah, and this was a mistake.

(Sunan ibn Majah 2045)

Comment: ? Did I ? I wrote that I made a mistake ???

Answer (score 0):

Yeah its a ghunnah, you did 2 sins overtime. 1 is not learning rules about ghusal and the other by doing things that you werent allowed to do when ghusal was farz on you. But just touba right from it and sadqah if you can.