# Is prayer accepted without ghusl and is he forgiven if he doesnt know ghusl is compulsory?

Tags: halal-haram, ghusl

Salaams, this is awkward but still...
Does discharge due to erotic books necessarily require ghusl? Or woudhu sufficient to start your next prayer?

Incase if a person doesn't know, that you cannot pray without ghusl and had prayed his obligatory prayer so many times only with woudhu, would he be forgiven and prayer be accepted?

Comment: Please search the site and ask one question per post. Both of your questions are already answered on the site: [What things require performing ghusl?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/62855/) and [Have I sinned if I did not perform ghusl because of ignorance?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/71381/)