# Solo penetration while being a boy

Tags: sin, punishment, men

السلام علیکم

I have made a mistake & now I'm regretful. I got a bit too much turned on & in that i not only masturbated but also used an object for my anal. I haven't been with another guy but did it myself. Will Allah forgive me or does it comes in zina?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will Allah forgive me for doing X ? (reference question)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/71337/will-allah-forgive-me-for-doing-x-reference-question)

Answer (score 0):

I'll just tell you to repent to Allah. And don't worry about what happened. Just repent and don't do this again.