# Have I committed shirk and if yes how do I get forgiven

Tags: shirk

I am 14 currently and not yet become baaligh( mature) but I accidentally committed shirk when I posted a TikTok video believing it would give me good luck I have done this on many occasions and recently I came across a video claiming to make these are shirk I’m scared now because I have been unaware of what I was actually doing and now I have come to realise I have committed the biggest sin which Allah hates.Will it count yet even though I’m not baaligh? If yes where do I go from here?

Comment: Please forgive me my ignorance, but *how*, really ***how*** do you come to think that posting a video would bring you good luck?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will Allah forgive me for doing X ? (reference question)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/71337/will-allah-forgive-me-for-doing-x-reference-question)

Answer (score 0):

Becoming baaligh is not determined solely by age. Age is only one sign of reaching the age of maturity (baligh). Some boys may reach the age of puberty, known as baligh, sooner or later, typically around the age of 15.

Regarding the video, if posting it is a sin, then delete it and ask Allah for forgiveness. Even if you are an adult, Allah still forgives those who ask for forgiveness and strive to correct themselves.