# Will Allah forgive me after doing a Sin a second time?

Tags: allah

Salam Alaikum, will Allah SWT forgive me for stealing? I used to do it a few years ago and did it again today and now i‘m feeling so much regret and pain because i know i shouldn‘t have done it. Will Allah SWT forgive me? I can‘t stop thinking about it and I feel terrible

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will Allah forgive me for doing X ? (reference question)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/71337/will-allah-forgive-me-for-doing-x-reference-question)